# Forgot Password User Flow Not Wokring Azure AD B2C Msal Android

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have implemented Azure AD B2C using MSAl Library on My Android App, The Userflow for `SignIn and  SignUp` is working as expected. but when i tried to click the `ForgotPassword` On My App, I'M getting the below error :

error:

Authentication failed: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalServiceException: AADB2C90118: The user has forgotten their password.
Correlation ID:

I have Implemeted B2C `createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication` on  my App.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

(1) Implement forgot password within the current policy (sign in/sign up) as explained by [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset) sample. It will not trigger any error since forgot password is embedded within the policy.

(2) You handle `Authentication failed: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalServiceException: AADB2C90118` error in your application. Your application should then initiate a new OIDC request against your b2c policy that is handling forgot password. Technically, now you have two authorities -- see sample config below and notice distinct authorities for  `b2c_1_susi` and `b2c_1_forgot_password` representing sign/sign and forgot password polices respectively. In this case try using `createMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication` as showcase by this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java)

```
{
 *   "client_id" : "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6",
 *   "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp/1wIqXSqBj7w%2Bh11ZifsnqwgyKrY%3D",
 *   "account_mode" : "MULTIPLE",
 *   "broker_redirect_uri_registered": false,
 *   "authorities": [
 *     {
 *       "type": "B2C",
 *       "authority_url": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/tfp/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi/",
 *       "default": true
 *     },
 *     {
 *       "type": "B2C",
 *       "authority_url": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/tfp/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_edit_profile/"
 *     },
 *     {
 *       "type": "B2C",
 *       "authority_url": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/tfp/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_forgot_password/"
 *     }
 *   ]
 * }
```

Comment: how to initiate a new OIDC request against your b2c policy that is handling forgot password in  `createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication`??  is it using the `AquireTokenParameter` . For `createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication` they use a `signin` method call for authentication. i didn't find AquireToken as used by `MultipleClientApplication`. Is it ok, if i use `AquireTokenParamater` for calling the `forogotPasswordPolicy` in `SingleAccountPublicClientApplication`??

Comment: I used `AquireTokenParamater` in `CreateSingleAccountPublicClientApplication` when i was trying to call the `ForgotPasswordPolicy` provided the authority URL as needed for the `passwordPolicy`. Now i'm getting the Forgot Password Page . is it recommended to use that?

Comment: Each policy, like ```ForgotPasswordPolicy```

Comment: @Razi- yeah! can i use `AquireTokenParamter` for `CreateSingleAccountPublicClientApplication` when calling `ForgotPasswordPolicy` ??

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so the way forgot password works in B2C is that if the user clicks the "I forgot my password" link,
they will be sent back to your app with an error.

Your app needs to handle this error and trigger authentication again but this time with the forgot password flow instead of the sign in/signup flow.

Comment: For `createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication' in **B2C** how can we invoke the  userflow for `Forgot Password`.